# Strange behavior with a foreign key relationship and custom user model

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a django (1.8.6) site that involved two applications now.  One is a custom user model with basic registration / login / logout functionality, the second is a feedback application.  I want to have a foreign key relationship from a feedback to the user that submitted it.

When I try to run ./manage.py migrate I get the following error.

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "customauth_user" does not exist

This is of course since the database table does not YET exist.  If I remove the related field, everything works fine.  Here is my code.

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=100, unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(('email address'), max_length=254)
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(_('lat_name'), max_length=50)
receive_newsletter = models.BooleanField(_('receive_newsletter'), default=False)
referral_id = models.CharField(_('referral id'), max_length=40)


USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

And the model from my feedback form:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='feedback')
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
message = models.CharField('Users message', max_length=1024)
reviewed = models.BooleanField('Reviewed by staff', default='NEW', choices=FEEDBACK_STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=10)
jira_ticket_created = models.BooleanField('Created a Jira ticket to track this feedback.',
                                          default=False)
jira_ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'feedback'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.timestamp) + ' ' + self.title
```

I have configured my user model in settings, added both applications, and in my installed applications my applcaition with my custom user model is first.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency in your feedback migration to the customauth app. See the [migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations).

Comment: That fixes it!  Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `python manage.py makemigrations`
and then `python manage.py migrate`